# MotionLayout visual glitch on first touch

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I'm working with a new `MotionLayout` from the `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2` package.

But I'm witnessing a visual glitch which happens the first time I'm touching the screen. I've got `OnSwipe` implemented for `dragDirection="dragDown"`but if I do a drag up before any other action it will show me the end state of animation.
Unforunately, I can't upload a GIF that would show it as it's too big. So I'm attaching all the code:

**EDIT**
Attaching a video - https://youtu.be/CYZy_Kt_LH0

**scene_03.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <Transition
      motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
      motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
      motion:duration="10000">

    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/hpImage"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
        motion:dragDirection="dragDown" />
  </Transition>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/hpImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/tvHp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"
        android:text="Harry Potter"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/hpImage"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hpImage"
        />

  </ConstraintSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/hpImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility = "invisible"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      >
    </Constraint>

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/tvHp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Harry Potter"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/hpImage"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/hpImage"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hpImage"
        />
  </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

**activity_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_03"
    android:background="@color/whiteSecondary"
    tools:showPaths="true">

  <View
      android:id="@+id/colorBackground"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/hpImage"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/hpImage"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/hpImage"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hpImage"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/hpImage"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/hp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvHp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
      android:textSize="24sp"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="Harry Potter"
      android:textColor="#fff"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/hpImage"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hpImage"
      />

</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution about this ? I find something there but not working -> https://github.com/mtcn/MotionLayoutExamples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/layout/motion/motionlayoutexample/DemoActivity.kt

Answer (score 1):

possible fix in alpha 3 version of constraintlayout https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/12/constraintlayout-200-alpha-3.html